# Approximating class rank

Tags: distributions, z-score

It is known that the top 10% of students make the Dean's list and that the top 20% earn honors.  It is also known that the minimum GPA for Dean's List is 3.84 and for honors is 3.66.  How would I approximate the class rank of a student with a GPA like 2.4?  It is given that there are 1000 students in the class and that the distribution is normal.

Comment: Not that difficult but not that accurately. For one thing, the normal approximation is vague enough in reality that the errors may be large. For example, the minimum GPA is truncated by dismissal from the roster, and the maximum GPA is 4.0 which is not a normal distribution limitation either.